# How can I use subprocess.run() in a detached process

Tags: python, subprocess

In a python script, I want to call `subprocess.run()` multiple times with varying arguments. While this initially works fine from the cli, it fails when the script is detached from the shell, eg with `script.py &`

As an example, lets transcode a folder of .wav files.

```
from glob import glob
import subprocess as sp

for w in sorted(glob('*.wav')):
    sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', w,
        '-f', 'mp4', '-vn', '-acodec', 'libfdk_aac',
        '-ac', '2', '-ab', '196k', f'{w}.m4a'],
        capture_output=True)
```

How can I get this script to run detached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was unable to find a solution on the web, I did find an option to make this work, so I am documenting it here for others.

Enabling `start_new_session` was the solution for me, this is a `Popen` option that gets passed on in the underlying code.

```
from glob import glob
import subprocess as sp

for w in sorted(glob('*.wav')):
    sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', w,
        '-f', 'mp4', '-vn', '-acodec', 'libfdk_aac',
        '-ac', '2', '-ab', '196k', f'{w}.m4a'],
        capture_output=True, start_new_session=True)
```